# Aligning two divs vertically

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` as:

1. div1 and div2 should be below one the another.
2. div2 will be at the bottom
3. div1 should adjust to the rest of the height above div2
4. div1 should also have a scroll bar(div2 doesn't need a scroll bar)

Code Snippet

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="div1" style="position:relative;overflow-y:scroll;width:340px;float:left;display:inline-block"></div>
  <div id="div2" style="float:left;clear:left;display:inline-block"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: add some code that you use to check it for you

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Your question is not really about "aligning two divs vertically"; it's more about "dynamically adjusting height of divs arranged vertically".;

Comment: As posted, `flexbox` solve this most of the time, the question is how the height is defined/set on your `outer` div and which browsers to support, as this can cause issues in some of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox does this for a living.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px red solid;
}

.div1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 340px;
}

.div2 {
  border-top: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <div class="div2">I am div 2.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Flexbox does this for a living.`++

Answer (score 0):

To activate `overflow-y` i.e. scrollbar on `.div1` content present inside it needs to `overflow` it, as below,

```css
#outer{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#outer > .div1{
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
  background:#f2f;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#outer > .div2{
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  background:#f22;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="div1">Div1 Demo text Demo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo text Demo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo textDemo text.</div>
  <div class="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```